# GeoWebCache hit miss

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache, arcgis-runtime

I am using geoserver 16.0 stored in Tomcat and arcgis Runtime SDK 100.6. I am using a WMTS protocol on the communication and I am connection directly with the gwc:
"http://localhost:8070/geoserver/World/gwc/service/wmts?REQUEST=getcapabilities"
My problem is that when trying to get tiles from the gwc, it's always returning a 
geowebcache-cache-result = MISS, even though the folder of gwc is growing up with the cached tiles, but it does not give me any further info on what's the problem.
When using a 12.something version of geoserver directly with the windows installer, not storing it in Tomcat, it is getting a HIT on the gwc result, but I need to use last version because of an improvement it has.

Comment: The response should contain also a "geowebcache-miss-reason" header, what does it say?

Comment: It should contain it but it does not. Maybe it's a new geoserver version's matter but there's no info on what's the problem.